# trouble with if condition

Tags: javascript

i call this function like this: `calculate(2)`

```
function calculate(flag)
{
   if (flag==1)
   {
   }
   else if (flag==2)
   {  
   }
   else (flag==3)
   {  
   }
}
```

In the debugger i see, that it jumps also to else `(flag==3)` (apart from  else if `(flag==2))`.
Could someone explain it to me?

thanks
H.Bada

Comment: The debugger is jumping there because that's a syntax error

Answer (score 6):

Please post your code using the `{}` code button so that it shows up nicely!

You don't want the final `else (flag==3)` you either want `else if (flag==3)` or just `else`

eg

```
function calculate(flag)
{
   if (flag==1)
   {
   }
   else if (flag==2)
   {  
   }
   else if (flag==3)
   {  
      //this will execute if flag is 3
   }
}
```

or

```
function calculate(flag)
{
   if (flag==1)
   {
   }
   else if (flag==2)
   {  
   }
   else
   {  
        //this will execute if flag is not 1 or 2
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is being interpreted like this:

```
if (flag == 1)
{
}
else if (flag == 2)
{
}
else
{
    (flag == 3)
}
```

You probably want another `else if` statement:

```
else if (flag == 2)
{
}
else if (flag == 3)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things are going on, and you're being confused by a syntax error:

```
 else (flag==3)
```

`else` doesn't take a boolean condition like `if` and `else if` do.

See @El Ronnoco's post for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As else doesn't check any condition so from your example **(flag==3)** is considered as the statement enclosed in your else block i.e. the first statement after **else** & everything else after that statement is out of the if... else block.

So every statement thereafter will be executed regardless of the value of your variable flag.